# How to send value from one js file to another

Tags: javascript

```
var script_1 = 'http://another_site.com/js/script_1.js';

$.getScript( script_1, function() { //Load script 1

    console.log('done loading script 1'); //Great! now append script 2 to the head tag

    var script_2 = document.createElement("script");

    script_2.innerHTML = " myobj.Widget({uid: 'Some value'});";

   // Appending to the head tag
   document.head.appendChild(script_2);
   console.log('done appending to the head tag');
 });
```

Basically, what I am trying to accomplish is to send the object value **uid** to the **script_1.js** file which is on another server.

**myobj** is defined in **script_1.js**. So **script_1.js** needs to finish loading before I can pass uid to it. The issue is that **script_1.js** still can't see the value **uid**.

Is there any better way to accomplish this? Thanks

Comment: Jummy. Cookies :). Or AJAX with PHP(or any server-side language you use) to set a session/flashdata variable.

Comment: This is why we use modules that declare their dependencies. Check out http://requirejs.org/